# How to return generated array from c function to objective-c

Tags: objective-c, c

Need to generated some random 10 byte length string in c function and call the function from objective-c. So, I'm creating a pointer to uint8_t and passing it to C function. The function generates random bytes and assigns them to *randomString. However, after returning from function to objective-c randomValue pointer points to NULL.

Here's my random function in C:

```
void randomString(uint8_t *randomString)
{
  randomString = malloc(10);

  char randomByte;
  char i;
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    randomByte = (rand() % 255 ) + 1;
    *randomString = randomByte;
    randomString++; 
  }
}
```

Here's objective-c part:

```
uint8_t *randomValue = NULL;
randomString(randomValue); //randomValue points to 0x000000

NSString *randomString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:randomValue length:10 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Random string: %@", randomString);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointers are passed by value, so `randomValue` will remain `NULL` after the call of `randomString`. You need to pass a pointer to a pointer in order to make it work:

```
void randomString(uint8_t **randomString) {
    *randomString = malloc(10);
    // ... the rest of your code goes here, with an extra level of indirection
}

uint8_t *randomValue = NULL;
randomString(&randomValue);
```

Comment: exactly what I was thinking! :)

Answer (score 3):

A more natural semantic, like `malloc()` itself would be:

```
uint8_t * randomString()
{
    uint8_t *randomString = malloc(10);
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        randomString[i] = (rand() % 254) + 1;
    return randomString;
}
```

Comment: This also works and reads better `uint8_t *randomValue = randomString();`

Answer (score 1):

You probably should be using `uint8_t **randomeValue` instead of `uint8_t *`.